# Drag'n Drop : tell the sender when drop occurs

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm using c# 3.5 / winforms

On my form, I have 2 picturebox PB1 and PB2 (and lots of others controls), in a panel.
The user can drag PB1 to PB2. But he can also cancel the drop by release the left button anywhere on the form or outside the form.
PB1 can be dragged a fixed number of times. When the drag start, I decrease a variable in PB1 and if it reach 0, the PB became invisible.

But if the user cancel the drag, PB1 must know that to increase the variable and set the visibility of PB1.

My problem is : how PB1 can know when a drag is canceled (or actually, dropped, even on a valid control) ? Remember that the user can release the drag outside of the form, so I can't use the Drop event on the form. I try the GiveFeedback and the QueryContinueDrag events, but they are fired as long as the drag continue, but not when it stop.

Some code :

```
class COPGOJetonImage
{
    private PictureBox PB1;

    public COPGOJetonImage()
    {
        PB1 = new PictureBox();
        //here I initialize PB1
        ((Control)PB1).AllowDrop = true; //in case of
        PB1.MouseDown += OnMouseDown;
    }
    public void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs ev)
    {
        PB1.DoDragDrop(PB1.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
```

Comment: "_The user can drag PB1 to PB2._"  Is PB2 the only valid drop target?  If the only place it can validly be dropped is somewhere in your form, then it would probably make more sense to decrease your variable when a drop occurs.

Comment: `DoDragDrop` is a method returning a result effect set by the drop target

Comment: Actualy, there is 1 to 4 valid target.

Comment: oups ! Actually, there are 1 to 4 valid targets. And I need to change the appearance of PB1 when the user drag the last instance. So if the user drop onto one valid target, PB1 remains (visually) disabled. But if he drop everywhere else (on the form or others windows or the desktop), PB1 must show an enable appearance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*there are 1 to 4 valid targets.*"

In this example we are dragging `pictureBox1`, and `pictureBox2` thru `pictureBox5` are the valid drop targets.  We create a DataObject with a custom name to encapsulate `pictureBox1` during the drag/drop operation.  In the drop targets, we only allow a drop if the custom name is present in the thing being dragged.  This ensures we only get a DragDrop event from `pictureBox1` itself, and we know it's safe to decrement our drop counter.  We can retrieve `pictureBox1` back from the DataObject and change its state so that it can no longer be dropped:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int DropsLeft = 5;
    private string DataFormatName = "YourUniqueDataFormatNameHere";

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.MouseMove += PictureBox1_MouseMove;

        PictureBox[] pbs = new PictureBox[] { pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4, pictureBox5 };
        foreach (PictureBox pb in pbs)
        {
            pb.AllowDrop = true;
            pb.DragEnter += Pb_DragEnter;
            pb.DragDrop += Pb_DragDrop;
        }
    }

    private void PictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormatName, pictureBox1);
            pictureBox1.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }

    private void Pb_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormatName))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void Pb_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DropsLeft--;

        // retrieve the data
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)e.Data.GetData(DataFormatName);

        if (DropsLeft == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No more drops left!");
            pb.Enabled = false;
            pb.BackColor = Color.Red; // for visual effect
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I will use it because it's seems impossible to do what I really want. Actually it's only a part of the problem. With your method, PB2/PB5 knows the source of drag and can tell the source that the drag is finished. But if the user releases the drag anywhere (on the form or on another window or on the desktop) except on PB2/PB5, the source doesn't know it.

Comment: Or I need that, so PB1 can react before the drag is released : the user starts the drag, PB1 change its appearance (for example, a number on PB1 to show how many times PB1 can be dragged, and a disabled appearance if no more drag is possible). If the drag object is released on PB2/PB5, PB1 keep its new appearance. But if the user release anywhere else, PB1 must change to its old appearance. So how PB1 can know that ?

Comment: You can change the appearance of PB1 before calling `DoDragDrop()`, this is trivial.  Create a `bool` variable and set it to `false` before the drag begins.  When a valid drop is made, toggle the flag.  The call to `DoDragDrop()` is actually **blocking**, so you can check the flag afterwards to see what happened.

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't realized that DoDragDrop is blocking !